# Symfony2.3 issue with translations

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, translation, xliff

I just try to translate my symfony 2.3 website, but I have an issue that I can not understand.

Here are my steps:

1. added translator:      { fallback: %locale% } in my config.yml, where %locale% is 'en' in my parameters
2. I use the filters in my templates and extract all translatable texts with the JMS translate commande in app\Resources\translations\messages.fr.xliff.

   3. set the local of the users in a listener.

Now, 60% of my XLIFF is translated in french, And when I try to test the result, symfony does not use my file (in the cache folder I just have catalogue.en.php)

I'm working on this for hours and I reaaly don't know why it does not work.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: what shows  $this->get('request')->getLocale() ?

Comment: In the profiler, all the locals are set to french

Comment: That's strange, everything is shown as fr in the profiler, but  $this->get('request')->getLocale() print en.
I just modified my listener and now it's set to fr.
Thank you, it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to meteor, I understood why my listener was not working.

Here is how I set  my local to make it work in all cases:

```
 $request->attributes->set('_locale', $locale);
 $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
 $request->setLocale($locale);
```